# Phonegap Build ignores android-minSdkVersion

Tags: web-applications, phonegap, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Phonegap and Phonegap build projects are not working at device running Android 4.2. Lat week everything was ok, but now deviceready event does not fire. I figured out, that phonegap cli 6.5.0 set android version to 6.x.x.

How can I make these projects run undel old versions of Android (not only 6 +)?

This code in config.xml does not work

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="15" />
</platform>
```